# Error code 1073741502 when running psexec through TeamCity

Tags: windows, teamcity, psexec

I have a build step that needs to run a console application under a different (more privileged) user account.

However PsExec always returns with the exit code -1073741502.

I thought the issue was from my app but when I replace with the following it still fails:

```
PsExec.exe -accepteula -u Username -p Password "cmd.exe" /C
```

Or

```
PsExec.exe -i -accepteula -u Username -p Password "cmd.exe" /C
```

Note that TeamCity build agent runs under a user account created specifically for it. When I manually log in as that user and run the above commands they work fine.

Comment: You get good google hits from "psexec status_dll_init_failed".  You'll need to improve your question from there.